# Each Row without using cursor in Composite key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
    DECLARE @CustomerID INT = 0

    -- Iterate over all customers
    WHILE (1 = 1) 
    BEGIN  

    -- Get next customerId
    SELECT TOP 1 @CustomerID = CustomerID
    FROM Sales.Customer
    WHERE CustomerID > @CustomerId 
   ORDER BY CustomerID

  - - Exit loop if no more customers
   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;

 -- call your sproc
    EXEC dbo.YOURSPROC @CustomerId

END
```

How can I use this code when my table has composite key.. I don't have single primary key. I have composite  "AppID" and "OriginID". How I can apply this logic?

Comment: What, this question is unclear.  Please provide table structure, sample data, and expected results.  As is, there's no way this can be answered...

Comment: This is superstition. If you're going to iterate over rows, you're already duplicating the worst aspect of cursors from which the "don't use cursors" over-applied advice stems. So why not be honest and use the functionality built into the system for iterating over rows - the cursor. Alternatively, determine if `YOURSPROC` can be re-written to be set based and eliminate the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although my post is not direct the answer to OP while try to use while and select top 1 (set based loop)  to avoid cursor (row by row ) (as given in the title "without cursor"), but provide other solution for such a problem.

Select top 1 within loop doesn't help in performance gain, because select top 1 lead to table scan and logical read ~2-3 for every row in the table (I used customer table in northwind to measure logical read, with set statistic on)

If we use **FAST FORWARD CURSORS** , it will lead to 1 logical read per row, which is better than select top 1 , plus avoid complexity of where condition for composite key and order by, especially within while there is execution to stored procedure.